# Can’t see debug messages using RCLCPP_DEBUG

Tags: ros2, rqt, rclcpp

I can’t see messages using RCLCPP_DEBUG by terminal and rqt, but I can using other levels of verbosity( INFO, ERROR, FATAL…).Selecting debug in rqt to see those messages doesn’t work either.

I’m using rolling, working in C++ in a plugin of a controller and launching tb3_simulation_launch.py from nav2_bringup.

I also saw a post here where they recommended to set the environment variable:

`RCLCPP_LOG_MIN_SEVERITY=RCLCPP_LOG_MIN_SEVERITY_DEBUG`

but that didn’t work either. It must be something silly that I’m missing. Has this ever happened to you?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding `arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "debug"],` to the Node which you are interested in at the launch file.

Or in the case where you seem to be using the nav2_bringup straight, you can change it at https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/ab9b1010d7a126c0c407cd09228d97068646ee4c/nav2_bringup/launch/navigation_launch.py#L134

You should also be able to give argument `log_level:=debug` when launching the launch file since that is being handled in [the launch file](https://github.com/ros-planning/navigation2/blob/ab9b1010d7a126c0c407cd09228d97068646ee4c/nav2_bringup/launch/navigation_launch.py#L119). Downside is that then all nodes will have debug level and there will be lots of extras

Example of launch file addition

```
    controller_server = Node(
        package="nav2_controller",
        executable="controller_server",
        output={"both": {"screen", "log", "own_log"}},
        emulate_tty=True,
        parameters=[],
        arguments=["--ros-args", "--log-level", "debug"],
     )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Adding log_level:=debug when launching the launch file worked perfectly. However, I couldn’t get it to work by modifying the launch file.

Comment: Great that you found this helpful. The modification of the launch file should also work. I have been using that for long time. Just have to be sure that the modified version is the one being ran. Added an example snippet from my code base.